# Dotnet Core 3.1 Entity Framework - Issues with entity.SetTableName not currently available

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Unfortunately I have found myself doing a full ground up rebuild with my code as the solution was taking 5 minutes to build. I decided to take the opportunity to move to dotnet core 3.1.

However, I have found that the option `.SetTableName` is not available as part of "entity".

I am using it as part of setting shadow properties in the DbContext. Here is my code.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            //entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName(); // Dotnet Core 2...
            entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());  //HERE
        }

        modelBuilder.ShadowProperties(); // Adding in the shadow properties here..
        ...
```

Is there another way to set the table name in this scenario and if not are there other options?

Comment: I think the last section of [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/167) might be related to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you, You can use **Data Annotations** or **Fluent API**

**Data Annotations:**

```
[Table("blogs")]
public class Blog
{
  public int BlogId { get; set; }
  public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Or:

```
[Table("blogs", Schema = "blogging")]
public class Blog
{
   public int BlogId { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().ToTable("blogs", schema: "blogging");
```